In Netflix's "Bodies,' how can DeFoe still know this information?
In the 2023 Netflix series Bodies, episode 5, DeFoe tells Maplewood that

 he and his Chapel Perilous buddies have tried multiple ways of preventing Mannix from using The Throat time travel machine, and all these ways have failed.

How can DeFoe know this?

 Does he keep his memories of all previous individual loops and the strategies they used in each of them?

Transcript of the relevant part:

 DeFoe: We couldn't kill Mannix, so we tried to destroy The Throat. We've tried to bury it, obstruct it. Nothing seems to work. ...
 The most I can do is drain it, deplete it, keep it weak. There's a dark energy field around it. Whilst that's there, it can't be used. But it won't last. He is coming, and he will use it. We've seen my body die.

Answers from the original comic book are also acceptable.

"We've seen my body die" - Body, singular. So he knows he tried to travel to stop Mannix once (at least). Rest of the transcript seems to refer to things Chapel Perilous tried not so long ago before this dialog happens, in this specific loop.

Also the Detective Hasan, leader of Chapel Perilous, have seen the body from one of previous loops.

@p4ulie ah yes, he could indeed mean that the list of actions are things they tried in this specific loop, I hadn't considered that. And they conclude that the actions don't work because they still exist
